# how to save pdf files using html-pdf-node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to save pdf file in current directory but its not.
its creating buffer but not saving file.

```js
var html_to_pdf = require('html-pdf-node');

let options = { format: 'A4' };
let file = { content: "<h1>Welcome to html-pdf-node</h1>" };
html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options).then(pdfBuffer => {
  console.log("PDF Buffer:-", pdfBuffer);
});
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow pritesh! i'm not sure if the code above is what you have tried given it looked eerily similar to the example code in the package's description. did you encounter any errors or something? let us know - with verbatim message if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the html-pdf-node documentation: [Html-pdf-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node)

The documentation says this:

`path`  The file path to save the PDF to. If path is a relative path, then it is resolved to current working directory. If no path is provided, the PDF won't be saved anywhere.

The `file` parameter serves as an object you can specify the `file.path` to save the pdf to a specific path.

```
let options = { format: 'A4' };
let file = [{ 
  url: "https://example.com", name: 'example.pdf', path: 'path/to/save/file' 
}];

html_to_pdf.generatePdfs(file, options).then(output => {
  console.log("PDF Buffer:-", output); // PDF Buffer:- [{url: "https://example.com", name: "example.pdf", buffer: <PDF buffer>}]
});
```